# How can I script a field in Kibana that matches first 4 digits of a field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm having a steep learning curve with the syntax and my data has PII so I don't know how to describe more.

I need a new field in kibana in the already indexed documents. This field "C" would be a combination of the first 4 digits of a field "A" that contains numbers up to millions and is of type:keyword, and a field "B" that is type:keyword and is some large number.
Later I will use this field "C" that is a unique combination, to compare with a list/array of items ( I will insert the list in a query DSL in Kibana, as I need to build some visualizations and reports with the returned documents).
I saw that I could use painless to create this new field, but I don't know exactly if I need to use regex and how to.

EDIT:

As requested more info about the mapping with a concrete example.

```
"fieldA" : {
        "type: "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
           }
          }
        },
"fieldB" : {
        "type: "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
           }
          }
        },
```

Example of values:
FieldA = "9876443320134",
FieldB = "000000001".
I would like to sum the first 4 digits of FieldA and the full content of FieldB. FieldC would result in a value of "9877".

Comment: Please use concrete examples instead.

Comment: Hi @Joe, just edited. Hope that I could provide a concrete example with the mapping. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw query could look like this:

```
GET combination_index/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "a+b": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def a = doc['fieldA.keyword'].value;
          def b = doc['fieldB.keyword'].value;
          
          if (a == null || b == null) {
            return null
          }
          
          def parsed_a = new BigInteger(a);
          def parsed_b = new BigInteger(b);
          
          return  new BigInteger(parsed_a.toString().substring(0, 4)) + parsed_b;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note 1: we're parsing the strings into `BigInteger` b/c of seemingly insufficient `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Note 2: we're first parsing `fieldA` and only then calling `.toString` on it again in order to handle the edge case of `fieldA` starting w/ 0s like `009876443320134`. It's assumed that you're looking for `9876`, not `98`, which be the result of first calling `.substring` and then parsing.

---

If you intend to use it in Kibana visualizations, you'll need an index pattern first. Once you've got one, you can proceed as follows:

[image]

then put the script in:

[image]

click save and the new scripted becomes available in numeric aggregations and queries:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Joe, thanks for the answer. I will try it today and reply here later.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Joe, had a few health problems. I marked your answer as accepted, as it helped me. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped!